# Extend abstract IntentService from Library result on Intent not found

Tags: android, intentservice

I'm building a library that I use then on my application. The idea is that the library has an Abstract class that extends from IntentService so that the app can create a subclass of this Service and manage the information there.

The problem is that I have declared MyIntentService that extends from the IntentService of the library, declared on the manifest but when I start to run it within the library the service can't be found.

Makes sense that is not found as from the library I don't know the new class I just try to open the one that is abstract from the library.

Any help is welcome, I'm a bit lost.

Library -> Abstract IntentService

```
public abstract class NotificationReceiver extends IntentService {

public NotificationReceiver() {
    super("NotificationReceiver");
}


public final void onHandleIntent(Intent intent) {
    L.d("NotificationReceiver","onHandleIntent","NEW MESSAGE");
    this.notificationReceived();
}

public abstract void notificationReceived();}
```

This does not get declared inside the manifest as it's abstract

App -> IntentService that extends the one from the library

```
public class MyNotificationHandler extends NotificationReceiver {

public MyNotificationHandler() {
    super();
}

public MyNotificationHandler(String name) {
    super();
}

@Override
public void notificationReceived() {
    Log.d("MyNotificationHandler","NEW NOTIFICATION TO DISPLAY");
}}
```

This is declared in the manifest of the application:

```
<!-- NOTIFICATIONS -->
    <service android:name="com.test.demosdk.MyNotificationHandler" >
    </service>
```

And the IntentService gets started from the library using this:

```
 Intent generalIntent = new Intent(DemoSDKManager.getApplicationContext(),NotificationReceiver.class);
        startService(generalIntent);
```

The above results on an IntentService not found.

Comment: As service needs paramterless contructor so make your abstract one have a constructor with parameters of ComponentName .... store it to use it inside library as Intent parameter to run it ....

Comment: Thanks @Selvin but not sure I understand. I have updated my question to show the code as stands now.

Comment: I did understand ... Ok ComponentName is bad idea ... better pass Class

Comment: Any idea how to pass the class? I can see that the name won't work as is not declared, but I don't know how to identify it instead.

Comment: Wait a minute why you need this `generalIntent`  ?

Comment: OK. Imagine this, from the Library I receive LocationUpdates on an IntentService. I want to notify the application about some of those updates. My idea was doing it with an IntentService as well, one that I describe as abstract on the library and that the app takes care of implement. The call to generalInetnt would be that, calling the IntentService that shoul be implemented (extended) from the application.

Comment: It would be better to not make it abstract and use BroadcastReceiver so user of the library would register for this broadcast ... added value you could add both receiver and service in library AndroidManifest and it would be merged into client manifest

Comment: Yes, broadcast receiver is an option. I'm just wondering how can this be done. I've seen it working. https://www.plotprojects.com/static/docs/android/com/plotprojects/retail/android/NotificationFilterReceiver.html  That library has a service (IntentService) that you can extend on your application. If you create your own extended version, it will get notified when necessary. And all this using IntentServices